# What is the -o option in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc

```
gcc -c x.c
```

tells the compiler to create the object code from the x.c file, and not try to link it, right?

What does the `-o` option tell the compiler as in the following?

```
gcc a.o y.o -o x.out
```

And the other question I have is, when I have source code like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    puts("");
}
```

Well OK, the compiler knows where to look for `stdio.h`, but the executable must be linked to `stdio.o`, mustn't it? Where does the `stdio.o` file reside?

Comment: See http://www.manpages.info/linux/gcc.1.html. Under the Synopsis section, you will see the `-o` option.

Comment: The C stadard library is usually called libc.a and is linked by default into any executable. Explicitly you can link it with `gcc -lc`

Comment: correction: `libc.so` is the one linked by default. The `libc.a` is the one for static linking. As for the location, there is already a question about it on SO (it's `/usr/lib`)

Comment: @a3f Thanks, I found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240639/where-is-the-standard-c-library-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html. Under the *Synopsis* section, you will see the [-o](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-o) option.

Regarding

> Well OK, the compiler knows where to look for `stdio.h`, but the executable must be linked to `stdio.o`, mustn't it? Where does the `stdio.o` file reside?

The answer to the first question is "No". Since the answer to the first question is "No", the second question is not relevant.

The functions and variables declared in `stdio.h` need not be in `stdio.o`. They are usually in a library (`.a` or `.so`) which are found in one of the directories where the linker looks for library files.

In general, there is no rule that each `.h` file has a corresponding `.o` file. It is possible to have the functions and variables declared in a `.h` file to be implemented in multiple `.c` files that will result in multiple `.o` files. It is also possible to have functions and variables declared in multiple `.h` files to be implemented in one `.c` file. How these are organized varies from project to project.

Each `.c` file, on the other hand, has a corresponding `.o` file (I haven't seen any platforms where multiple `.c` files can be compiled to create one `.o` file). All the `.o` files resulting from compiling the `.c` files are linked together to create an executable.

Comment: The link is broken (domain expired?): *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at www.manpages.info."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for pointing out the broken link. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

It indicates the output file, i.e. what your object-file or executable should be. You can see this information by doing `gcc --help` or `man gcc`.

`<stdio.h>` is part of the standard library, which your compiler is already linking to.

Comment: There is also [-o directly on one of the documentation pages](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-o) (more extensive), though all the options are spread out over more than 15 pages and are difficult to locate, to say the least.

Answer (score 3):

```
gcc -o [file]
```

[Writes the build output to an output file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-o). This is not to be confused with [-O](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O) which is the optimization level. I don't believe this option has anything to do with linking.