# What does "-o" means on shell command line?

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, visual-studio-code, command-line

I'm new to using command line and using C++. When I searched how to compile and run C++ code using terminal on Visual Studio Code, I got sample of compiling and running "hello world" program. The sample says

```
g++ -o hello.exe hello.cpp & hello.exe
```

I googled `-o` but it didn't hit(maybe because the word is too short). I don't know what `-o` means and don't even know what kind of shell(command prompt or powershell or something else) this command is for.

Comment: You don't need to put the `.exe` extension to generate the **output file**.

Comment: tip: `-foo` is google syntax to ignore results containing `foo`. Try `"gcc -o"` to find eg this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398522/what-is-the-o-option-in-gcc

Comment: Note that you should probably have `&&` rather than `&` here.  The `&` tells the shell to start the compiler in the background and run `hello.exe` -- which may not exist yet -- in the foreground.

Comment: `g++ --help` helps in this kind of cases

Comment: thank you all you. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

that means that `outfile` or **output** of the compiled code should be named **hello.exe**

> -o file
>
> Place output in file file.  This applies to whatever sort of
> output is being produced, whether it be an executable file,
> an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.
>
> If -o is not specified, the default is to put an executable
> file in a.out, the object file for source.suffix in source.o,
> its assembler file in source.s, a precompiled header file in
> source.suffix.gch, and all preprocessed C source on standard
> output.

here are more other [flags](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html)

Comment: Thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

It is specifying the name of output file.

[g++(1): GNU project C/C++ compiler - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++)

> -o file
>
> Place output in file file. This applies regardless to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.
>
> If -o is not specified, the default is to put an executable file in a.out, the object file for source.suffix in source.o, its assembler file in source.s, a precompiled header file in source.suffix.gch, and all preprocessed C source on standard output.

Comment: Thank you. I got it.