# How to compile and dump assembly for a c library (string.h)?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, objdump

For a school project I have to do a large amount of string manipulation in assembly.  Since this is a pain to do I was trying to come up with innovative ways to use already programmed string operations.  My idea is to compile and dump the assembly from the `string.h` library in c.  Then I would copy paste the dumped assembly into my program.  After figuring out the memory location of each function and it's parameters I figure I would essentially be able to call up the function.

To dump the assembly I first wrote a program that included the libraries I wanted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled and dumped the assembly using

```
gcc -o lib lib.c
objdump -d  *o
```

When I looked at the output I noticed that it didn't include any of the assembly for the libraries.  My guess is there is either a compiler optimization that doesn't include unused functions, or the library output is hidden when I use `objdump`:

```
lib:    file format Mach-O 64-bit x86-64

Disassembly of section __TEXT,__text:
__text:
100000fa0:  55  pushq   %rbp
100000fa1:  48 89 e5    movq    %rsp, %rbp
100000fa4:  31 c0   xorl    %eax, %eax
100000fa6:  c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
100000fad:  5d  popq    %rbp
100000fae:  c3  retq

_main:
100000fa0:  55  pushq   %rbp
100000fa1:  48 89 e5    movq    %rsp, %rbp
100000fa4:  31 c0   xorl    %eax, %eax
100000fa6:  c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
100000fad:  5d  popq    %rbp
100000fae:  c3  retq
```

As a side note I am running OSX Catalina, but I can switch to Ubuntu or a different OS if it would be easier.

How can I go about dumping the asm for the `string.h` library?

Comment: Just including the .h files will not add any functions to the program unless you actually call them. Also calling library functions doesn't add the assembly to your program it just links to the assembly in the shared library file.

Comment: Note that gcc has builtins for certain string functions, so with optimization enabled you may very well get code inlined (if you use the function that is). If you are interested in the library version you can of course disassemble the library itself without having to compile anything.

Comment: (A point for thinking outside the box. Unless your were actually supposed to write it yourself for that school exercise...) It should be possible to dump the contents of standard libraries as well.

Comment: Instead of including it, you could just look at the source straight away and try and compile that: [Linux string.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/lib/string.c)

Comment: @Frederik that link has nothing to do with the standard C library.

Comment: hah I see.. and by "innovative" you really mean "skirt the assignment"

Comment: The professor said he thought it was hard and said to see if I could get it to work

Comment: `string.h` is a header, not a library.  It does not contain code for any functions.  The code is in the dynamically linked libc.

Comment: @Jester Would it be easier to disassemble an already compiled binary instead of compile it myself and do an objdump?

Comment: You disassemble the library. See [Marco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60102543/547981)

Answer (score 4):

First, let me start by saying that this is really an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

> My idea is to compile and dump the assembly from the string.h library in c. Then I would copy paste the dumped assembly into my program.

You should *not* do that. The standard library has very meticolously optimized functions that need to be treated with care and are *very*, ***very*** complicated. They are, in other words, basically useless for educational purposes if you're learning assembly.

You should really just write your favorite implementation in C and then compile it.

---

A header file (such as `string.h`) usually does *not* contain function definitions. It only contains their declaration. The real functions are actually *already compiled* into a dynamic library object which is installed in your system (that is the library itself).

When you compile a program, the compiler automatically links it to the standard C library. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6240700/3889449), in OS X the standard library should be located at `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib`. On Ubuntu, it's usually `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`. The following applies to both platforms without a problem.

If you want to take a look at the disassembly of a particular library function you can run `objdump` on the library piping it into `less`, and then search for the function name:

```
$ objdump -d /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib | less
```

When inside `less`, you can search by typing `/` followed by the name of the function, and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and use <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>N</kbd> to navigate through matches.

Alternatively, you could dump the output of `objdump` to a file and inspect it with a text editor:

```
 $ objdump -d /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib > libSystem.disasm
```

The problem when doing this kind of thing is that the standard library has a lot of different and more complicated names for standard functions than the ones you see in `string.h`. Internally, the symbols used are different. For example, in Linux when using `printf` the corresponding symbol in libc is actually `__printf`. See [here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/printf.c.html#_IO_printf) for example.

You can find the real symbol name of a standard library function by compiling a program that uses it and looking at the disassembled code, for example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char s[100];

    scanf("%99s", s);
    size_t len = strlen(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Then run:

```
$ gcc prog.c
$ objdump -d a.out
...
0000000000000720 <main>:
 720:   55                      push   %rbp
 721:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 724:   48 83 ec 70             sub    $0x70,%rsp
 728:   48 8d 45 90             lea    -0x70(%rbp),%rax
 72c:   48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
 72f:   48 8d 3d ae 00 00 00    lea    0xae(%rip),%rdi        # 7e4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 736:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 73b:   e8 90 fe ff ff          callq  5d0 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>
 740:   48 8d 45 90             lea    -0x70(%rbp),%rax
 744:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 747:   e8 74 fe ff ff          callq  5c0 <strlen@plt>
 74c:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
 750:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 755:   c9                      leaveq
 756:   c3                      retq
 757:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 75e:   00 00
```

And you can see that in my case `scanf` is actually `__isoc99_scanf`, while `strlen` is unchanged.

I can then look up the disassembly of `strlen`, which on my system (Ubuntu) is the following:

```
$ objdump -d /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | less
...
0000000000080650 <strlen@@GLIBC_2.2.5>:
   80650:       66 0f ef c0             pxor   %xmm0,%xmm0
   80654:       66 0f ef c9             pxor   %xmm1,%xmm1
   80658:       66 0f ef d2             pxor   %xmm2,%xmm2
   8065c:       66 0f ef db             pxor   %xmm3,%xmm3
   80660:       48 89 f8                mov    %rdi,%rax
   80663:       48 89 f9                mov    %rdi,%rcx
   80666:       48 81 e1 ff 0f 00 00    and    $0xfff,%rcx
   8066d:       48 81 f9 cf 0f 00 00    cmp    $0xfcf,%rcx
   80674:       77 6a                   ja     806e0 <strlen@@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x90>
   80676:       f3 0f 6f 20             movdqu (%rax),%xmm4
   8067a:       66 0f 74 e0             pcmpeqb %xmm0,%xmm4
   8067e:       66 0f d7 d4             pmovmskb %xmm4,%edx
   80682:       85 d2                   test   %edx,%edx
   80684:       74 04                   je     8068a <strlen@@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x3a>
   80686:       0f bc c2                bsf    %edx,%eax
   80689:       c3                      retq
   8068a:       48 83 e0 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rax
   8068e:       66 0f 74 48 10          pcmpeqb 0x10(%rax),%xmm1
   80693:       66 0f 74 50 20          pcmpeqb 0x20(%rax),%xmm2
   80698:       66 0f 74 58 30          pcmpeqb 0x30(%rax),%xmm3
   8069d:       66 0f d7 d1             pmovmskb %xmm1,%edx
   806a1:       66 44 0f d7 c2          pmovmskb %xmm2,%r8d
   806a6:       66 0f d7 cb             pmovmskb %xmm3,%ecx
   806aa:       48 c1 e2 10             shl    $0x10,%rdx
   ...
   ...
```

As you can see, even such a simple function is actually a seemingly impossible to understand jungle of complicated instructions, due to the numerous optimizations and manual tuning applied by the authors of glibc over the years.

Comment: "Impossible to understand jungle of complicated instructions" is an exaggeration. Many people make their livings reverse engineering malware, for example, which is more complicated than strlen, since you know its purpose in advance. Of course I totally agree that attempting to reverse engineer loop-unrolled code to save time on a school assignment is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Gene: or if you want to understand glibc functions, read the *commented* hand-written asm source!  It uses some macros but otherwise looks like normal AT&T syntax. e.g. the SSE2 version https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S.html (See also [Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/57650895) for some info about the C fallback vs. hand-written asm versions, with links.)  Also glibc's memcpy / memset is nice, [using 2 overlapping stores for small buffers](//stackoverflow.com/q/51614543)

Comment: @Gene I know, I do some RE for fun myself, I was just talking from a novice point of view since OP is learning assembly. I might have exaggerated with the hyperbole there :') Though malware doesn't usually use all those fancy optimized opcodes, it's more self modifying and code obfuscation than absurd instructions.

Answer (score 2):

What you're proposing is a bad idea because production library code is compiled with optimization turned way up. Optimized code is not impossible to understand, but it can be complicated. Why? `gcc`, for example, will often choose vector instructions that you probably don't want or need to learn about. It will unroll simple loops into long stretches of repetitive code. It will rearrange instructions in unintuitive orders to keep the processor pipeline full. When you're learning, these are sources of confusion.

What you *can* productively do to learn is compile C with light optimization.

The [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Y8Dadu) is nice for this. Give it little code fragments and see what different compilers do with different optimization levels. The link above shows a `strlen`. [Here's](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/UBh6Vm) a `strcpy`. [Here's one that's not in the standard library at all](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fW53DU). It advances a pointer to char to either the end of string or the first appearance of a separator character. I.e., it's a simple string parser.

Answer (score 0):

Generic method:

1. find package, for Debian-like Linux:

```
$ apt-file search string.h
```

Of course, this is glibc.

2. get source e.g. glibc 2.31 and compile it:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-kernel=4.0.0 --disable-profile --with-gnu-ld --enable-stack-protector=strong
$ make
```

3. implementations of functions usually have the same name, so find source:

```
$ find . -type f -name "strstr.c"
```

this is strings/strstr.c

4. disassemble default compiled version:

```
$ objdump -d string/strstr.o > strstr1.asm
```

5. make new version with customized optimization:
   delete object file:

```
$ rm string/strstr.o`
```

remake with commands output:

```
$ make V=1 &>strstrr.txt
```

- this is for "bash", otherwise use "script" command

get gcc command from strstrr.txt, modify it as you want (optimization, processor type...), e.g. change -O2 to O10, and run:

```
$ cd strings
$ gcc ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strstr.c -c -std=gnu11 -fgnu89-inline  -g -O10 -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Werror -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -fstack-protector-strong -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -fmath-errno      -ftls-model=initial-exec      -I../include -I/home/yury/LFSC/cross1/src/bglibcn/string  -I/home/yury/LFSC/cross1/src/bglibcn  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/include -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86  -I../sysdeps/x86/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/include -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/nptl  -I../sysdeps/pthread  -I../sysdeps/gnu  -I../sysdeps/unix/inet  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/posix  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu/include -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/x86  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/float128  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96/include -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I.. -I../libio -I.   -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include /home/yury/LFSC/cross1/src/bglibcn/libc-modules.h -DMODULE_NAME=libc -include ../include/libc-symbols.h       -DTOP_NAMESPACE=glibc -o /home/yury/LFSC/cross1/src/bglibcn/string/strstr.o -MD -MP -MF /home/yury/LFSC/cross1/src/bglibcn/string/strstr.o.dt -MT /home/yury/LFSC/cross1/src/bglibcn/string/strstr.o
$ objdump -d string/strstr.o > strstr2.asm
```

the code will be different:

```
$ diff strstr1.asm strstr2.asm
```

So, you can copy-paste code you want into your assembler program to save your time.

Comment: Most of the glibc string functions have x86 asm implementations.  Compiling the generic fallbacks can give you some asm for an over-complicated version that probably does 4 bytes at a time with a bithack to check for possible end of string.  Or if you find https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strstr.c.html then you're looking at the dynamic linker runtime CPU-dispatch code that selects which actual implementation to resolve to, based on the host machine.  If you want to copy asm from glibc, you might as well just grab `x86_64/multiarch/strstr-sse2-unaligned.S` source

Comment: glibc is multiarch lib (without mobiles):
```
$ find . -type f -name "strstr.c"
./sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strstr.c
./sysdeps/powerpc/powerpc64/multiarch/strstr.c
./sysdeps/s390/strstr.c
./string/strstr.c

```
Another multiarch implementation of standard C library is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_(software)
Platform‎: ‎x86‎, ‎x86-64‎, ‎ARM‎, ‎ARM64‎, ‎MIPS‎, ‎MI...

Comment: glibc "multiarch" doesn't mean "portable", it means it handles runtime dispatch for a few variations of x86-64 CPU, or a few variations of PowerPC,  where the best choice of implementation is selected at dynamic-link time.  Glibc's *portable* fallback C implementation is https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strstr.c.html.  (This file is `#include<>`ed by the x86 multiarch .c file as a fallback for CPUs without efficient SSE2 unaligned loads/stores.  Other functions like `strchr` don't have a C fallback, always an asm version.)